# start/pause button with setInterval and clear

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a start button that contains both functions of starting and pausing. By using `setInterval` and `clearInterval`. Where should I begin for my approach? I was think something along:

```
var begin = document.getElementById("begin");
begin.addEventListener("click", startPause, false);

function startPause(){
   if(begin == false){
      clearInterval(draw);
   }else{
      setInterval(draw, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set your `setInterval` to a variable.

for example:

```
var autoRefresh = setInterval(function(){}, 1000);
```

this way, when clearing your interval you can just use:

```
clearInterval(autoRefresh)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `clearInterval` function is based on the interval index not on the function :

```
var begin = document.getElementById("begin");
begin.addEventListener("click", startPause, false);

function startPause(){
   if(begin == false){
      if(typeof loop != "undefined"){
          clearInterval(loop);
      }
   }else{
      var loop = setInterval(draw, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prepare sample code for your reference:

```
<button onclick="go(this)">start</button>
<div id="clock"></div>

<script language=javascript>
 var interval=null;
 function go(v)
{
   if (interval==null)
   { 
       interval=setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
       v.textContent="stop";
   }
   else
   { 
       clearInterval(interval);   
       v.textContent="start";
   }
}
function updateClock()
{
    var clock=document.getElementById("clock");
    clock.textContent=new Date();
}
```